# polymer.html: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have a Polymer web component that works stand-alone. However, upon bringing it into my app, I am getting a `TypeError` about `dispatchEvent`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'

*I am debugging this now but wanted to post this, as there isn't currently another single result that I can find about this error specifically related to Polymer.*

Comment: Is this Polymer element public that you could share its code here? I think we need more context to determine the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/krisrandall/bugle-reports-client

I think the issue is that the pathing for the <link>ed webcomponents is incorrect - I'm changing the structure this repo, so that the bower_components are in root (using a .bowerrc file) and I think that is going to do it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that *an earlier version of* **[JayData](http://jaydata.org/) is not compatible with webcomponents**.

I was using JayData and was on version 1.3.6.

I've downloaded and updated to the latest version (1.5.6) and this has fixed the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... now I'm very interested in any guides for upgrading my code from v1.3 to v1.5 of JayData as it has changed a lot ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884051/jaydata-how-to-migrate-code-from-v1-3-to-v1-5