# JayData : how to migrate code from v1.3 to v1.5

Tags: javascript, polymer, jaydata

I have some code which worked in JayData 1.3.

I need to upgrade JayData to 1.5 due to the compatibility issues the 1.3 version has with polymer.

The [upgrade instructions](http://jaydata.org/blog/release-notes#wptoc_4_2_3) say you can use the "`jaydata-compatibility.js`" script to "upgrade your app to JayData 1.5.x from previous versions step-by-step", however when I add that in as described I simply get the error, "**`typeOrName requires a value other than undefined or null`**", which actually doesn't help me step through the upgrade at all.

#### Here is the JayData 1.3 code :

```
$data.Entity.extend('Cache', {
    'id': { 'type': 'int', 'key': true, 'computed': true },
    'url': { 'type': 'string' },              
    'method': { 'type': 'string', 'required': true },   
    'dts': { 'type': 'string', 'required': true },    
    'encryptMeth': { 'type': 'string' },  
    'data': { 'type': 'string' }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend('APIWrapperDB', {
    'Cache': { 'type': $data.EntitySet, 'elementType': Cache }
});

var cacheDatabase = new APIWrapperDB('TheAPIWrapperDatabase');

cacheDatabase.onReady( function() { /* now my DB is ready */ };
```

#### What is the JayData 1.5 equalivalent of this code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the updated snippet, I've just declared your entity definitions as variables as JayData stopped using global objects.

```
var Cache = data.Entity.extend('Cache', {
    'id': { 'type': 'int', 'key': true, 'computed': true },
    'url': { 'type': 'string' },              
    'method': { 'type': 'string', 'required': true },   
    'dts': { 'type': 'string', 'required': true },    
    'encryptMeth': { 'type': 'string' },  
    'data': { 'type': 'string' }
});

var APIWrapperDB = $data.EntityContext.extend('APIWrapperDB', {
    'Cache': { 'type': $data.EntitySet, 'elementType': Cache }
});

var cacheDatabase = new APIWrapperDB('TheAPIWrapperDatabase');

cacheDatabase.onReady( function() { /* now my DB is ready */ };
```